# full screen app: stuck navigation bar

Tags: android, webkit, fullscreen, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I wrote an app that is composed by a full screen webkit object. So, as soon as the activity starts, i set these flags:

```
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
```

Problem is that when i swap down from the top border of the screen, status bar and navigation bar becomes visible (and this is ok, so you can close the app if you need it). Problem is that, after a few seconds, status bar goes away while navigation bar doesn't. It stucks there. Is there a flag I am missing? Or is there any hook I can use to detect when the status bar hides and then set back the flags?

Comment: Hey have you got any solution? I am stuck in this problem too